# Регулярка на php. Добавление слеш в конец URL

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть тексты в базе. В них есть ссылки без **слеша**, `(например: http://test.ru/category)`. Помогите с регуляркой, чтобы находила такие ссылки в тексте и добавляла к ним **слеш**.

В тексте есть еще такие URL - `(http://test.ru/category/post.html)`, к ним **слеш** не должен добавляться.

И еще вопрос. Как удалить слеш тут через регулярку `http://test.ru/category/post.html/`

Сайт на WordPress и сам запрос в базу и подмену написал, кроме регулярки.

Буду очень признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(.+[^.][^h][^t][^m][^l?])$` Найдет все URL которые не оканчиваются на .html и далее просто используйте замену вот по этой формуле `$1/`

https://regex101.com/r/2pwDan/1

по аналогии надо найти все кто оканчивается на .html/ и сделать замену.

`(.+\.html)(\/)$`, а в автозамену вписать уже только первую группу найденного: `$1`

Comment: [`(.+[^.html])$`](https://regex101.com/r/S2fmOs/1) находит любую строку, которая не заканчивается одним из символов в символьном классе `[^.html]$`. Так что это неверное решение.

Comment: соглашусь с предыдущим автором, это не работающее регулярное выражение. во-первых знак $ на конце подойдет только для ссылок в конце текста (автор писал, что нужно обрабатывать ссылки, находящиеся в самом теле текста). во-вторых, [^.html] - это неверно по целому ряду причин. выражение с этим кодом не найдет вообще ничего (точка спецсимвол, вы говорите скрипту "искать все кроме всех символов")) и даже без точки буквы html в квадратных скобках просто указывают на допустимые символы (точнее даже один символ!). под это подойдет любое упоминание и "h", и "t"

Answer (score 2):

Добавить слэш:

```
preg_replace('/\b(http:\/\/[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\/[a-z]+)\b/i', '$1/', $str);
```

Удалить слэш:

```
preg_replace('/\b(http:\/\/[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\/[a-z]+)\/\b/i', '$1', $str);
```

P.S. Для подобных замен (если формат URL четко определен) старайтесь использовать более жесткие конструкции и не применяйте регулярные выражения по упрощенному поиску (иначе будет много неверной обработки на больших данных).

Answer (score 0):

Регулярки работают, но не совсем как мне нужно было.
В моем случае она такая: `/href="([^\."]*(?!(\.html)))"/m` и заменяем на `href="$1/"`